# Need to transfer from one domain to another domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect permanent from one domain to another, such as:

```
http://www.example.de/page.html?cid=00340119050014953926&pc=70000
```

to this:

```
http://www.secondexample.com/page.html?cid=00340119050014953926&pc=70000
```

So it's a different domain with the same parameters.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be done with an htaccess redirect.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.secondexample.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your index file in your old domain to this:

```
<html>
<?php
    header('Location: http://www.secondexample.com/page.html?cid=00340119050014953926&pc=70000');
    exit;
?>
```

You can simply use a header redirect.

If you need to keep the old get data you can include simple parsing in yout old do,ain of the get data and use it in the redirect.

See [PHP header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for more info.

Comment: If someone directly enters this url : http://www.example.de/page.html?cid=00340119050014953926&pc=70000 then in this case index file will not be called. My main problem is it should be transferred to new domain in this case also keeping rest of parameter same.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to always redirect the `page.html` page to the new domain regardless of what's in the query string, you can do this in htaccess with something similar to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^page.html(.*)$ http://www.secondexample.de/page.html$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

If these domains are on a shared server and actually point to the same files as one another, you'll need to add a condition above the `RewriteRule` in the above:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.de$
```

Answer (score 0):

can be done using .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %QUERY_STRING ^(.+)$
RewriteRule page\.html http://www.secondexample.com/?%1 [R=301]
```